# Does morning and evening chanting follow a set pattern in the Theravada tradition?

Tags: theravada, temples, monastery, rituals

I attended a meditation event that included morning and evening chanting at a Theravada monastery/temple. It was a wonderful event but I couldn't follow the chanting book as it was written in Lao characters. I recognized some basics like taking refuge and eight precepts, but other than that I was lost. Does morning and evening chanting follow a set pattern or does each monastery just pick out what they like? If it is a set pattern, what might it include? I'd like to print out some in Pali/English if possible. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't want to answer without good sources, but Lao chanting seems to follow the same tradition as Khmer and Sri Lankan chanting. Thai chanting contains modern and distinct alternatives to the basic formula.

Comment: @yuttadhammo, good to know, I'll see what I can find outside of Thai chanting. Thanks Bhante.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the chanting services in Laos unfortunately. I do know about the general chanting services done in Thailand though, which might be similar although the Thai chanting I'm familiar with doesn't have the refuge and precepts as part of the chanting service itself.

If you want to check out a general Thai service book [here's](http://www.abhayagiri.org/books/abhayagiri-chanting-book) a good one. You can download the chanting book as a PDF and some sections have the Pali and English on seperate pages while some have the English underneath. I especially like this chanting book because it has the little arrows to indicate the chanting melody. You can also hear recordings of Monks chanting out of this particular book [here](http://www.abhayagiri.org/audio) if you go to the upper right and switch the category to chanting.

Answer (score 0):

[Pali Chanting](https://www.dhammatalks.org/chant_index.html) by the monks of Metta Forest Monastery can be found as audio here. A [text version](https://www.dhammatalks.org/ebook_index.html#chanting) incl.translation, corresponding, is also generously given.

Aside of chanting style, there are differents in regard of the set between Nikayas but even from monastery to monastery, also Nikayas from one country to another. In regard of the text within the single parts, there are also, but just small differences traceable. Generally the Dhammayut style most plain an undecorated is understood easy and from all others able to follow.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*